# Am I to calculate the 95% confidence interval in this question?

Tags: self-study, biostatistics

MI5 has finally decided that 007 doesn't have to be a man but they still need to be British and shorter than 175.3 cm.  The average height of all British citizens is 160 cm and the standard deviation for the population is 7.6 cm.  Type your answers below and show your work on a separate sheet.
If MI5 wanted to include 95% of the population, what would the height restriction have to be?
Initially, I used a Z-value of 1.96 to calculate the height restriction and I got 174.896. However, after thinking about it, I realized that I am supposed to calculate the height so that the Pr(Z)>0.05. Using this approach, I would have to use a Z-value of 1.64 to calculate the height using the equation $Z=\dfrac{x-160}{7.6}$. Am I understanding the question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the height (denoted by $X$) of British citizens follows normal distribution with mean $\mu = 160\,cm$ and STD $\sigma = 7.6\,cm$. Denote the PDF of $X$ as $f(x)$. What you should do is to find out the value of $z$, such that

$\int_{z}^{175.3} {f(x)}\,\text{d}x = 0.95$.